# Assigning "new Number" to prototype field prints as {} in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I'm trying following JavaScript example.

```
function A() {};

A.prototype.x = new Number(10);

var a = new A();

console.log(a.x);
```

In Firefox, its printing value as 10, but in Chrome or Node.js its printing as {}.

But when change the second line like below, then it prints 10 in chrome also

```
A.prototype.x = 10;
```

Can someone explain me the reason why new Number(10) is not working in chrome.

Comment: `console.log` wins again: Compare to `console.log("" + a.x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're making a Number wrapper object instead of a primitive, and that's Chrome's chosen representation. *(Console representations are not always the same. There's no standard.)*

The actual number `10` is stored in an internal property called `[[PrimitiveValue]]`, so it's not directly exposed.

To get its `[[PrimitiveValue]]`, you can use the `.valueOf()` method.

```
console.log(a.x.valueOf()); // 10
```

---

> **[15.7.2.1 new Number ( [ value ] )](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.2)**
>
> The `[[Prototype]]` internal property of the newly constructed object is set to the original Number prototype object, the one that is the initial value of `Number.prototype` (15.7.3.1).
>
> The `[[Class]]` internal property of the newly constructed object is set to `"Number"`.
>
> **The `[[PrimitiveValue]]` internal property of the newly constructed object is set to `ToNumber(value)` if value was supplied, else to `+0`.**
>
> The `[[Extensible]]` internal property of the newly constructed object is set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

`new Number(...)` creates a boxed Number instance, which is not the same as a number primitive.
Chrome's console displays that as an object.

If you write `console.log(new Number(10))`, you'll see the same output.

If you change your code to use a primitive (`A.prototype.x = 10`), it will show `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Because Number is an object. `console.log(a.x.valueOf());` or `console.log(a.x.toString());` will work.